# Using reinterpret_cast to read file into structure

Tags: c++, inputstream, binary-data, reinterpret-cast

```
struct DATAs
{
    char data1;
    short data2;
    short data3;
    float data4;
    int data5;
    short data6;
    unsigned short data7;
    short data8;
    char data9;
};

void fixFile(char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream InputFile;
    InputFile.open(filename, std::ios::binary);

    DATAs FileDatas;
    InputFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&FileDatas), sizeof(FileDatas));
}
```

Why do I need to use "reinterpret_cast" for the reading instead of

"InputFile.read(&FileDatas, sizeof(FileDatas))" ?

Comment: You also need to be aware of whether the file is in Big Endian or Little Endian format. Some are in a mix of the two (e.g. MS .wav files).

Comment: Also ... the struct DATAs might be a different size if they were created on a different compiler, or with different compiler options,  And the compiler (that built the file) might 'pack' the struct differently (than your compiler).  Your testing should include confirmations.  Which implies you need to be able to describe the correct memory layout.  Neither C nor C++ provide memory layout semantics.

Comment: The structure of the flie are known and tested, copied the struct from a similar program's source code, here I found this cast method so that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the first argument to `std::ifstream::read()` is `char*`. A pointer of type `DATAs*` is not automatically cast to `char*` in C++. Hence, you need to use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: You also need to be aware of whether the file is in Big Endian or Little Endian format. Some are in a mix of the two e.g. (MS .wav files).

Answer (score 0):

This code is a undefined behavior.
Class fields can be aligned to some specific address to improve performance.

Also sizes of types are not well defined, so if you compile your program for 32 or 64 bits you can have different results.

And there is also an endian issue.

It is recommended do not read data using this approach.

Comment: The structure of the flie are known and tested, copied the struct from a similar program's source code, here I found this cast method so that is why I am asking.

Comment: I'm sure it works with one compiler with specific compiler options, but if you change: compiler or its options or platform, you will have a nasty bug.